# sed equivalent to PCRE's `.?`

Tags: php, regex, sed, pcre

I'm trying to find all instances of `aaa` and replace it with `bbb` but preserving the first character preceding the `aaa`. Here's how I'd do it in PHP with PCRE:

```
preg_replace('#(.?)aaa#', '\1bbb', 'aaasdfg');
```

How would I do something like that with sed? Here's my attempt (didn't work):

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/(.\?)aaa/\1bbb/g' filename.ext
```

It's a bit of a contrived example. What I'm trying to do is a little more complicated but, long story short, I'm trying to get `.?` working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the first character of aaa always an a? For the slow folks like me: Maybe you could post a few examples of how a few strings are supposed to be converted.

Comment: `aaasdfg` gets converted to `bbbsdfg`. `xaaasdf` gets converted to `xbbbsdf`. So it's not the first character of a but whatever character precedes `bbb`.

Comment: I don't get it. How is this different from `sed -i.bak -r 's/aaa/bbb/g' filename.ext`? I mean, regex replacement always preserves *everything* preceding the match-string; you don't need to do anything special for that.

Comment: Why use sed in the first place? Surely you have perl and php on that machine.

Comment: I read your question wrongly just now. Now I updated my answer, I think your problem should get solved. you got confused by the escapes...;)

Comment: @ruakh - quoting my OP, _what I'm trying to do is a little more complicated but, long story short, I'm trying to get `.?` working_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just now I mis-read your question, I thought you want to do `.*?` with sed. ..

Ok, now I understand what you mean. In another question from you, I mentioned, for BRE, you have to escape those chars to give them special meaning.  But for ERE, you have to escape chars which have special meaning to get literal string.

You used `-r`, to let sed use ERE, but you escaped `?`, it means, you want to match literal string `?`.

try this:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/(.?)aaa/\1bbb/g' filename.ext
```

or this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(.\?\)aaa/\1bbb/g' filename.ext
```

test:

#### default with BRE

```
kent$  echo "aaasdf
xaaasdf"|sed 's/\(.\?\)aaa/\1bbb/'
bbbsdf
xbbbsd
```

#### with -r, ERE:

```
kent$  echo "aaasdf
xaaasdf"|sed -r 's/(.?)aaa/\1bbb/' 
bbbsdf
xbbbsdf
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out whatever it is the OP wants. I still don't know why `s/aaa/bbb/` isn't adequate.